# What is the right implementation for a singly linked list?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I'm preparing for coding interviews, and studying Singly Linked Lists, I found 2 books implementing them in 2 different ways:

1. The HEAD pointer is pointing to a node which element is None and its reference is the actual first node. (If the Linked list is empty, HEAD and TAIL are pointing to this particular node)
2. The HEAD pointer is pointing to the actual first node directly. (If the Linked list is empty, HEAD and TAIL are pointing to None Object)

So, which is the best implementation to know for coding interviews?

Comment: AFAIK, the 2nd approach is the standard way of implementing a singly linked list.

Comment: There is no one right choice. What matters is that you choose the implementation that will best meet the needs of the *user* of the data structure. What operations will be performed on the list? What are the memory and time constraints imposed on the implementations of those operations?

Comment: The first way is odd, but someone might have a good reason for it in special circumstances.  Use the second way unless you have a good explanation for why you used the first way.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use the second approach. The first approach has one node when actually we have zero entries in the list. For me its easier to understand if a list is empty or not in the second case. If someone asks you in the interview why the choice of that strategy just make sure every edge case is covered in your answer.